# CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]) returns as null on Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, ckeditor

I'm using [this directive](http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/cPTr7/) to use CKEditor in Angular. In IE8, Firefox and Chrome Desktop it works fine, but Chrome on my Nexus 5 it throws and error `Cannot read property 'on' of null`.

In the jsfiddle the errors is line 10, so `CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);` is returning null. Does anyone know why this is returning null, or how I can debug this further to find the underline problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see apparently CKEditor isn't really Android compatible, so I'll look for a different WYSIWYG.

Comment: Is there any workaround that anyone has come up with? This is pretty blocking for a cordova app I have

Comment: I've not found anything yet, fortunately for us a normal textarea was good enough.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor 4 [supports mobile versions](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_browsers.html#a-word-about-mobile-environments) of Safari (default browser on iPhone and iPad) and Chrome (available for Android and preinstalled on many Android devices) with minor issues related to platform limitations.

**Can CKEditor Be Enabled in Unsupported Environments?**
[Yes](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_unsupported_environments.html#can-ckeditor-be-enabled-in-unsupported-environments)

Answer Source: [This Article](https://support.ckeditor.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002452469-Is-CKEditor-4-compatible-with-iPhone-iPad-Android-and-other-mobile-devices-)

Answer (score 0):

For those wanna switch on the compatibility flag then may look up here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_unsupported_environments.html#changing-the-enviscompatible-flag

It did solve the issue and hopefully all the market mobile browser can work.